# apache2 ignoring the default host and always redirecting to domain, even when using the IP

Tags: apache2, vhosts

I am trying to make apache2 use a default site when a user access my server by IP address, instead of inputing the site's domain, just to tell the user he cannot access the ip directly.

What is happening is that it keeps redirecting to the domain's site, overwriting the IP address in the browser, instead of showing the default site.

Note the domain's site is redirected to https, this is expected.
The default site is not using ssl at all, and preferably should not use ssl.

My sites config are as folow (without logging, error documents nor ssl pathes directives):
000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example.com/www
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

example.com-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example.com/www

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

All these sites are enabled and apache2 have been restarted.

```sh
> $ sudo apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:*                    1.2.3.4 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:443                  example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

`http://example.com` and `https://example.com` behave as expected.
`http://1.2.3.4:80/` unexpectedly redirects to `https://example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid `<virtualhost *>` which amounts to `<virtualhost *:*>` which is really quite unusual.    It is also a bad idea to omit ServerName from any virtualhost, because it will be plucked from the systems hostname and cause confusion.

Apache picks the best matching IP:PORT combination first, then looks at ServerName/ServerAlias from the set of virtualhosts with that best match.

This is why your `*:80` virtualhost is selected -- it's a more specific match.

Comment: Thanks, this appear to be the reason.
I have seen countless examples where `<virtualhost *>` is used to set the default.